# Using pluck with joins and ordering on the first model using Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
#  web_page_id        :integer
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :web_page
end

class WebPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
end

class BookmarkGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :web_pages, through: :bookmarks
end
```

WebPage has a status field and I am trying to get the web_page_ids of the most recent 5000 bookmarks (created_at DESC) or a BookmarkGroup for which their WebPage status is nil. Getting the bookmark objects works with the following query:

```
bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order('created_at DESC').limit(5000)
```

However, I just want to get the web_page_ids and not have to load 5000 Bookmark model instances in memory, but when I use pluck(:web_page_id) at the end, I get, 'PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous' and if I reference bookmarks in the order like this:

```
bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order('bookmarks.created_at DESC').limit(5000).pluck(:web_page_id)
```

I get: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "bookmarks"

Comment: try changing .pluck(:web_page_id) to .select(:web_page_id).to_a

Comment: what is the output of `puts bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order('bookmarks.created_at DESC').limit(5000).to_sql`?
what about `bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order(bookmarks: { created_at: :desc }).limit(5000).pluck(:web_page_id)`?

Comment: @bkunzi01 this gives me: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "bookmarks"

Comment: @faron puts bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order('bookmarks.created_at DESC').limit(5000).to_sql: SELECT  "os_items".* FROM "os_items" INNER JOIN "web_pages" ON "web_pages"."id" = "os_items"."web_page_id" WHERE "os_items"."type" IN ('Bookmark') AND "os_items"."bookmark_group_id" = $1 AND "web_pages"."status" IS NULL  ORDER BY bookmarks.created_at DESC LIMIT 5000

Comment: @faron bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order(bookmarks: { created_at: :desc }).limit(5000).pluck(:web_page_id) leads to the following error: 'ArgumentError: Direction should be :asc or :desc'

Comment: so `bookmarks` table is called `os_items`, what about `bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order('os_items.created_at DESC').limit(5000).pluck(:web_page_id)` then?

Comment: or just `bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).where(web_pages: {status:nil}).order(created_at: :desc).limit(5000).pluck(:web_page_id)`

Comment: @faron Ah, yep, both of those work! Thank you! If you want to add those as answers I can select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've found in discussion that actual table name for `bookmarks` is `os_items`, so there're two options:

Straightforward:

```
bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).
  where(web_pages:{status:nil}).
  order('os_items.created_at DESC').
  limit(5000).
  pluck(:web_page_id)
```

(also possible: `.order("#{Bookmark.table_name}.created_at DESC")`)

Keeping in mind that Rails would put table name of current scope holder:

```
bookmark_group.bookmarks.joins(:web_page).
  where(web_pages: {status:nil}).
  order(created_at: :desc).
  limit(5000).
  pluck(:web_page_id)
```

In case order should be performed by `web_pages` [merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) would be helpful: `.merge(WebPage.order(created_at: :desc))`

Another option would be to use `Arel` for this.